# Issue trying to build error chart in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm attempting to build an error chart using D3 that looks like this:
[image]

The issue I'm having is that maximum error square (the square at the top) isn't showing up. Here's what I have so far:

```
var m = { top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10 }
var h = 400 - m.top - m.bottom;
var w = 500 - m.left - m.right;
var r = 5;

var data = [
  { x: 0, y: 12, yMin: 10, yMax: 20 },
  { x: 1, y: 25, yMin: 17, yMax: 30 },
  { x: 2, y: 15, yMin: 12, yMax: 17 },
  { x: 3, y: 10, yMin: 5,  yMax: 14 },
  { x: 4, y: 5,  yMin: 1,  yMax: 6  }
]

var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.x } )])
  .range([0, w]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.yMax } )]) 
  .range([h, 0]);

var vis = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr({
    height : h + m.top + m.bottom,
    width  : w + m.left + m.right,
  }) 
  .append('g')
    .attr({
      transform : 'translate(' + m.left + ',' + m.top + ')'
    })

var scatterPlot = vis.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr({
      x      : function(d) { return xScale(d.x) - r; },
      y      : function(d) { return yScale(d.y); },
      width  : r * 2,
      height : r
    });

var errorMin = vis.selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr({
      cx : function(d) { return xScale(d.x); },
      cy : function(d) { return yScale(d.yMin); },
      r  : r
    });

var errorMax = vis.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr({
      x      : function(d) { return xScale(d.x) - r; },
      y      : function(d) { return yScale(d.yMax); },
      width  : r * 2,
      height : r * 2
    });
```

And here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/du37ep71/2/

I am pretty sure that when I do `var errorMax = vis.selectAll('square')` at the end of my code it's telling D3 to select the existing squares rather than appending new ones, and I'm sure there's a way to just append new squares, I've just been unable to figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.append('square')` => `.append('rect')`

Pre-defined SVG shapes that can be appended

1. Rectangle `<rect>`
2. Circle `<circle>`
3. Ellipse `<ellipse>`
4. Line `<line>`
5. Polyline `<polyline>`
6. Polygon `<polygon>`
7. Path `<path>`

### [w3 source](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_rect.asp)

```
var errorMax = vis.selectAll('square')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr({
        x      : function(d) { return xScale(d.x) - r; },
        y      : function(d) { return yScale(d.yMax); },
     width  : r * 2,
     height : r * 2
});
```

### [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/du37ep71/1/)

Comment: Wow, thank you. Can't believe it was such a small typo.